# Ampliar al tamaño exacto del div

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Estoy tratando de acomodar dos div que están dentro de un div en forma de columna, y de paso que estos ocupen el espacio restante de este.

[image: menu]

Por ejemplo el div principal es el de color azul, el cual ocupa el espacio como tal que le otorgue, dentro del están, el div de color rojo el cual tiene el icono, y el de color verde que tiene el texto.

La idea es que el verde, quedo en el fondo de este div, osea en el `bottom` y del ancho del div del color azul, y el rojo ocupe el espacio restante, tanto hacia arriba como hacia abajo y a los lados, sin que afecte el tamaño original del azul.

#### html

```
<div class="container">

          <!--Fila Uno-->

          <div class="cell-row cell-row-1">

            <div class="cell-1 color-novedad">
              <a href="#/perfilestu">
                <div>
                  <div class="color-segundo"><i class="ion-ios-person-outline"></i></div>
                  <div class="color-prueba">Perfil</div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="cell-2">
              <a href="#/horarioestu">
                <div>
                  <div><i class="ion-ios-time-outline"></i></div>
                  <div>Horario</div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html,
body,
.scroll
/* because the <ion-content> content is placed inside a div.scroll */

{
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container > .cell-row {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
}

.cell-row > div {
    flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    color: dimgrey;
    /* Flex for these containers (cells) */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.color-prueba{
    background-color: green;
    flex: 0 0 25px 100%; 
    width: 100%;
}

.color-segundo{
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1 100%; 
    width: 100%;
}

.color-novedad{
    background-color: blue;
}

.container i[class^="ion-"] {
    font-size: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El elemento `.color-novedad` no tiene mucho sentido que sea `flex` ya que dentro tiene un elemento `a` que a su vez tiene un elemento `div` el cual es donde están las cajas que deseas acomodar.

```
.color-novedad {
  display: block;
}
```

Segundo, tanto al elemento `a` como `div` debes darle un alto del 100% para que ocupen el alto del padre.

```
.color-novedad > a,
.color-novedad > a > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Tercero, hay que hacer flexible el elemento `.color-novedad > a > div` con orientación vertical; esto nos ayudará a que `.color-segundo` se estire.

```
.color-novedad > a > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Cuarto, le damos `flex: 1` a `.color-segundo`, para que **ocupe el espacio restante**.

```
.color-novedad .color-segudo {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Finalmente, le damos un `flex-basis` de `35px` de alto a `.color-prueba` y un `line-height` de igual cantidad para que el texto de centre verticalmente.

```
.color-novedad .color-prueba {
  flex: 0 0 35px;
  line-height: 35px; /* centrado vertical */
}
```

Al darle `flex: 0 0 35px` a `.color-prueba`, hacemos que solo ocupe `35px` del espacio total del contenedor flexible y, además, con `flex: 1` en `.color-segundo` le decimos que ocupe «el espacio restante».